# Node.js Winston logging Info on console

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

In my node app I'm using winston t. How can I use winston to log info in the console as well as the normal file logging?

```
const winston = require('winston');
winston.add(new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logfile.log' }));
// preparing listening ports
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    winston.info(`Listening to port ${port}....`);
});
```

I want info: Listening to port 3000 to be printed in my console.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's described in the [documenation](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#using-the-default-logger), basically you can simply add both `transport` methods, e.g.:

```
const winston = require('winston');
const fileAppender = new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logfile.log' });
const consoleAppender = new winston.transports.Console();

winston.add(fileAppender);
winston.add(consoleAppender);
```

Comment: @Hasan: any feedback?